# Video crash randomly for no apperent reason

Tags: android

I build a video player that works most of the time. But it may crash for no apparent reason. The player plays videos in loop, sometimes it crashes on the second movie and sometimes it work for hours straight. It always plays the same movies, so the problem is not it them.

My log:

```
10-09 13:24:23.251: E/MediaPlayer(620): error (1, -1007)
10-09 13:24:23.251: E/MediaPlayer(620): Error (1,-1007)
10-09 13:24:23.251: D/VideoView(620): Error: 1,-1007
```

Comment: Can you post the code.

Comment: Wow, very same problems here. I have found results varies a lot betweeen Android devices. Same file goes fine for hours then all of a sudden exceptions. I use VideoView but am currently replacing code to use directly MediaPlayer class. It requires extra code but nothing major. Will see if problems go away. I'll let you know how it goes.